# t-student distrubition

Tags: probability

I have 2 questions about t distrubition

1- from t distrubition table find:

(a) $t_{(17,0.95)}$

(b) $t_{(15,0.5)}$

my answer:

(a) $t_{(17,0.95)}$=-$t_{(17,0.05)}$ = $-1.740$

(b) $t_{(15,0.5)}$=$2.602$

true?

2-fint the point t such that:

$P[-t\le t_{(20)}\le t ]=0,95$

(less than or equal)

i can't solve it.

t distrubition table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your last question, take into consideration that the t-student is symmetric with respect to the y-axis. If I am not wrong, your question is related to the called two sided distribution (have a look to wikipedia's article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution).

If you want $P[-t\le t_{20}\le t]=0.95$, it means that $0.05$ of the curve is not in the interval you are looking for. As it is symmetric, the $0.025$ of the distribution should be in the interval $(-\infty,-t]$ and another $0.025$ on $[t,\infty)$. It means that you have to look to the value $\alpha=0.025$ in your table and $n=20$. So, the solution would be $t=2.086$.